# Google Chrome cookies, from Mac OSX to Windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, file-transfer, cookies

Basically my old computer broke so while I was waiting until Christmas to get a new one I had to play games, on [Kongregate](http://www.kongregate.com/), on a Macbook Pro. I now have my new computer and was wondering how to transfer the cookies onto my Windows computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Chrome signed into a user profile, you can copy the profile data and transfer it:

**On your Mac:**

- Open a new Finder window
- Press CommandShiftG
- Type in ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default

**To import into your Windows machine:**

Close any Chrome windows and move your "Default" folder copy into

%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\ on any computer with Chrome installed.